# How to check all S.M.A.R.T. logs location

Tags: 14.04, ntfs, disk, smart

As in S.M.A.R.T log:

> device log contains only the most recent five errors

Is there a possibility to see all logged errors of a S.M.A.R.T Enabled disk?

```
smartctl -xall
```

or

```
smartctl -all
```

The two commands above just show the last five and I need to retrieve the LBAs with problems to write zeroes to it and check the S.M.A.R.T again.

Comment: First, your commands are wrong. Use this: `sudo smartctl --xall /dev/sda` and `sudo smartctl --all /dev/sda`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have installed `smartmontools`, and enabled `smartd` then all log entries are available in `/var/log/syslog`:

```
grep "smartd" /var/log/syslog*
```

For `/dev/sda`

```
grep "smartd.*/dev/sda" /var/log/syslog*
```

An other example:

```
$ grep "smartd.*/dev.*failure" /var/log/syslog*

/var/log/syslog:May 14 10:46:58 sturm smartd[608]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Prefailure Attribute: 1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate changed from 120 to 104
/var/log/syslog:May 14 10:46:58 sturm smartd[608]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], SMART Prefailure Attribute: 1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate changed from 117 to 119
/var/log/syslog.1:May 13 05:30:33 sturm smartd[631]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], SMART Prefailure Attribute: 1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate changed from 110 to 113
/var/log/syslog.1:May 13 11:19:26 sturm smartd[651]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], SMART Prefailure Attribute: 1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate changed from 113 to 115
/var/log/syslog.1:May 13 11:49:26 sturm smartd[651]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Prefailure Attribute: 1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate changed from 120 to 100
/var/log/syslog.1:May 13 11:49:26 sturm smartd[651]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], SMART Prefailure Attribute: 1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate changed from 115 to 117
/var/log/syslog.1:May 13 15:49:27 sturm smartd[651]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Prefailure Attribute: 1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate changed from 100 to 102
/var/log/syslog.1:May 13 19:49:26 sturm smartd[651]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Prefailure Attribute: 1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate changed from 102 to 104
/var/log/syslog.1:May 14 10:16:58 sturm smartd[608]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Prefailure Attribute: 1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate changed from 104 to 120
```

Comment: It's a good answer, but this only works if you have already installed the `smartmontools` which are not installed by default.

Comment: Yes, that's true. I will change my answer. And +1 for your answer.

Comment: You got my +1.  It is always good to see more ways of doing things that sometimes you forget about.  Thank you!

Comment: In fact, Ī̲ don’t see anything really informative. Mostly ❝Device: /dev/nvme0, number of Error Log entries increased from ### to ###❞.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the log on the drive itself contains only the last 5 errors.  If you want to see the LBAs, you could run badblocks from a terminal window.

`sudo badblocks -sv /dev/sdX`

That will run a complete surface check on your drive and show you the locations of any bad blocks.